# Joining Multiple Tables with 2 aggregated tables

Tags: mysql-5.7

I'm using mySQL 5.7 
I have seen this question a couple times and it seems like the answer was followed exactly but only my first row of data is correct.

I'm trying to join 3 tables 2 of them are aggregated. The sum of listed quantity
is correct on the listings table.

> ```
> Select Sum(listings.Quantity) As Cnt, product.ProductId 
> from product
> left join listings on listings.ProductId = product.ProductId And
> ProductTypeId = 4 
> Group By product.ProductId 
> order by ProductId asc;
> ```

Then the next table is a sum of the sales using the same id from the product table. I get the correct sum.

> ```
> Select Count(sales.SalesPrice) As NumSld,Sum(sales.SalePrice) as Sld 
> , ProductId 
> from product
> left join sales on sales.ProductId = product.ProductId And
> ProductTypeId = 4 
> Group By product.ProductId 
> order by Sld asc;
> ```

Here is the attempted Join of the tables

> ```
> Select t1.Cnt, pro.ProductId, t2.NumSld, t2.Sld
> From product pro
> Left Join (
>           Select ProductId, ProductTypeId, Sum(Quantity) As Cnt
>           From listings
>           Group By ProductId
>           ) t1 on t1.ProductId = pro.ProductId and t1.ProductTypeId = 4
>
> Left join (
>            Select ProductId, ProductTypeId, Count(SalePrice) as NumSld,
>            Sum(SalePrice) As Sld
>            From sales
>            Group By ProductId
>            ) t2 on t2.ProductId = pro.ProductId and t2.ProductTypeId = 4
> Order by t2.Sld desc;
> ```

The data returned on this is incorrect. Only the first row is correct. I think its something simple that I'm missing. I have been stuck on this for days. Can anyone figure it out?

Comment: Are you sure you meant to select t2.NumSld and not t1.Cnt? You aren't selecting anything from t1.

Comment: I'm Selecting the Sum(Quantity) of listings in the listings table.....  t1.Cnt. I'm also getting a Count(SalePrice) and Sum(SalePrice) in the sales table t2 Something is wrong with syntax of the Left Join. When I join separately the data is correct. I'm still stuck on this. It's driving me nuts. :(